# UnknownPropertyException in Yii2 RBAC with yii2-user module configuration

Tags: php, yii2, rbac, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I get the following error while configurating the yii2-module in advanced template:

```
exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Getting 

unknown property: common\models\User::status' in D:\Programes instal.lats\xampp\htdocs\yiitester\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php:143
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Programes instal.lats\xampp\htdocs\yiitester\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\BaseActiveRecord.php(246): yii\base\Component->__get('status')
#1 D:\Programes instal.lats\xampp\htdocs\yiitester\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\validators\DefaultValueValidator.php(46): yii\db\BaseActiveRecord->__get('status')
#2 D:\Programes instal.lats\xampp\htdocs\yiitester\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\validators\Validator.php(238): yii\validators\DefaultValueValidator->validateAttribute(Object(common\models\User), 'status')
#3 D:\Programes instal.lats\xampp\htdocs\yiitester\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Model.php(333): yii\validators\Validator->validateAttributes(Object(common\models\User), Array)
#4 D:\Programes instal.lats\xampp\htdocs\yiitester\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\ActiveRecord.php(416): yii\base\Model->validate(NULL)
#5 D:\Programes instal.lats\xampp\htdocs\yiitester\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\BaseActiveRecord.php(582): yii\db\ActiveRecord->insert(true, NULL)
#6 D:\Programes instal.lats\xampp\htdocs\yiitester\frontend\models\SignupForm.php(51): yii\db\BaseActiveRecord->save()
#7 D:\Programes instal.lats\xampp\htdocs\yiitester\frontend\controllers\SiteController.php(123): frontend\models\SignupForm->signup()
#8 [internal function]: frontend\controllers\SiteController->actionSignup()
#9 D:\Programes instal.lats\xampp\htdocs\yiitester\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 D:\Programes instal.lats\xampp\htdocs\yiitester\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(151): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#11 D:\Programes instal.lats\xampp\htdocs\yiitester\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(455): yii\base\Controller->runAction('signup', Array)
#12 D:\Programes instal.lats\xampp\htdocs\yiitester\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(83): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/signup', Array)
#13 D:\Programes instal.lats\xampp\htdocs\yiitester\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#14 D:\Programes instal.lats\xampp\htdocs\yiitester\frontend\web\index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#15 {main}
```

I have followed these instructions:

https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/master/docs/usage-with-advanced-template.md

Installed with composer:

```
composer require "dektrium/yii2-user:0.9.*@dev"
```

And edited the required files:

**common/config/main.php:**

```
<?php
return [
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'modules' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            // you will configure your module inside this file
            // or if need different configuration for frontend and backend you may
            // configure in needed configs
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
            'defaultRoles' => ['guest'],
        ],
    ],
];
```

**frontend/config/main.php**

```
    <?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'modules' => [
        'user' => [
            // following line will restrict access to admin page
            'as frontend' => 'dektrium\user\filters\FrontendFilter',
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ], 
    ],

    'params' => $params,
];
```

I'm new with yii2-user and rbac.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command to run the migration:

```
php yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/migrations
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `yii migrate` command.

Comment: Please add some more detail explaining _why_ and _how_ this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.0.12 you may also specify an array of migration paths that should be searched for migrations to load.

in console config you could add:

```
'controllerMap' => [
    'migrate' => [
        'class' => MigrateController::class,
        'migrationPath' => [
            '@app/migrations',
            '@vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/migrations'
        ],
        'migrationNamespaces' => [
        ],
    ],
]
```

if you run the

php yii migrate/up

then @vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/migrations will be included all the time.

the advantage is that you will not run into an error if one of the updates comes with a migration

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a status column into your user table, just like below:

> alter table user add `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you skipped third part of installing `dektrium/yii2-user` package. And that is applying migration that comes with the package. By runiing these migrations you ensure that in your database you will have tables needed for correct functionality of the package. Some of them is `user` table for example.

This is what you skipped from instalation guide:

> ## 3. Update database schema.
>
> The last thing you need to do is updating your database schema by applying the     migrations. Make sure that you have properly configured db application component and     run the following command:
>
> $ php yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/migrations

Look [here](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)